# Laravel MS SQL DB::RAW Query returns "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using SQL Server within my Laravel application. I need to group/sum a table for the month/year. My query looks like this:

```php
$positions = BelegPos::select(
    DB::raw("YEAR(Datum) as year"),
    DB::raw("MONTH(Datum) as month"),
    DB::raw("SUM(Menge) as stunden")
)->groupBy("year", "month")
    ->get();
```

I'll get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Invalid column name 'year'.

I don't know what's wrong, as the query the way I build it works fine with MySQL servers.

Thanks for any hint in the right direction.

## UPDATE

I researched a bit more and read about somthing that points out, that the Select Statement isn't available in the GROUP BY section and that you have to add the same query there. so my query looks now like this:

```
$positions = selectlineBelegPos::select(
                                        DB::raw("YEAR(Datum) as the_year"),
                                        DB::raw("MONTH(Datum) as the_month"),
                                        DB::raw("SUM(Menge) as stunden")
                                        )
                                        ->groupBy(DB::raw("YEAR(Datum) as the_year"),DB::raw("MONTH(Datum) as the_month"))
                                        ->get();
```

Still not the solution but the error message has changed to this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword (SQL: select
> YEAR(Datum) as the_year, MONTH(Datum) as the_month, SUM(Menge) as
> stunden from [BELEGP]

So I think there is just one small thing wrong but can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Comment: @DaleK `YEAR` isn't a reserved (key)word, just a keyword, in T-SQL. It *is* however a Reserved Keyword in ODBC: [ODBC Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Is it case sensitive?  Because invalid column name is year, lower case, doesnt say anything about the YEAR in the top part.

Comment: Try renaming `as year` to `as the_year` or similar to see if it fixes the issue, or (and I'm not certain if it works) surrounding year in square brackets (`as [year]`)

Comment: Unfortunatly non of your hints worked out. It just changes the error message. It seems to me like the DB::RAW Query from the select statement isn't available in the groupby. Maybe here is something to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Just found the the solution:

```
$positions = selectlineBelegPos::select(
                                       DB::raw("YEAR(Datum) AS year"),
                                       DB::raw("MONTH(Datum) AS month"),
                                       DB::raw("SUM(Menge) AS stunden")
                                       )
                                       ->groupBy(DB::raw("YEAR([Datum])"),DB::raw("MONTH([Datum])"))
                                       ->get();
```

Indeed isn't the dynamically value names (year and month) unavailable in the GROUPBY clause, instead you have to call the DB::raw again but now without generating the key words again.

thank you all for the support!

Comment: Thank you too. Nice you could resolve the problem. Please chose your own answer as correct and close the issue.